# ssh -T git@bitbucket.org showing incorrect id in powershell

Tags: powershell, git-bash

In **git bash** this is correctly reflecting my id. But when it comes to **powershell** it shows my older Id. Not clear whats the problem. I closed and restarted the powershell, but still the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I did

```
Stop-SshAgent
```

and then I did

```
Start-SshAgent
```

Now things seems to be correct.